# Amazon AWS + Postfix. 3 out of 5 emails fail to send over SMTP due to Timeout

Tags: laravel, email, amazon-web-services, smtp, postfix-mta

I am having a hard time setting up Postfix on my Aws Ubuntu server. I started with a clean server and installed Sentora and Laravel.

1.First I have opened port 25 on AWS Securty.

2.Than I have configured email in Laravel:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=my-domain.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=office@my-domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=false
```

3.Than in index.php I try  a simple test:

```
<?php
// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

After 5 test emails, I end up with 2 in my inbox (yahoo), due to:

> Connection could not be established with host my-domain
>   .com
>   [Connection timed out #110]

If I run a test on POSTFIX via terminal I get the following:

```
ubuntu@cpanel:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 cpanel.pe-scena.ro ESMTP
ehlo localhost
mail from: office@my-domain.com
rcpt to: vedt@yahoo.com
data
Subject: My first mail on Postfix

Hi,
Are you there?
regards,
Admin
.250-cpanel.my-domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 20480000
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
250 2.1.0 Ok
250 2.1.5 Ok
403 4.5.0 <DATA>: Data command rejected: Improper use of SMTP command pipelining
221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: You're getting the error when testing because SMTP requires that you wait for each response before sending the next command, hence the server's response "I can break rules, too."  But first, you need to request AWS remove the outbound restriction on your account.

Comment: thanks, I have contacted Amazon.